# How do I create a java desktop application in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've got a bunch of data stored in tables through Mysql on which I've done some analysis and also export microsoft excel to make graphs and such but the customer wants it to be a desktop application which I have never done before. Currently working in Eclipse. What is the simplest (or any really) way to make a desktop application?

EDIT: I don't think I was clear and that is my fault. I know how to make a GUI in Eclipse I just don't know how to make the desktop icon that will bring up the GUI I make.

Comment: The answer to this, to put it simply, isn't so simple.

Comment: Ok. Really any way to do it then.

Comment: [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Comment: This question is entirely out of scope for Stack Overflow.  Asking us how you would build an entire application is unreasonable to ask of us here.  I would encourage you to read [about what's on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Comment: I guess its my unfamiliarity with GUIs and possibly not enough information in the question. I know how to build a GUI that works well enough but I run it through eclipse. I just want to know how to make the icon that will bring up the GUI I make.

Comment: The JFrame setIcon method.  The icon can be a png file that you can make in any paint program.

Answer (score 0):

For beginners you can start with Swing or [JavaFx](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm). It's easy to learn plus they have some excellent tutorials or you can look use more mature Java Frameworks such as Apache Struts, Spring MVC etc.

You can also try netbeans IDE. It has native support for building JavaFX Application and Swing application.

Just make sure you install required plugin to setup your environment in eclipse. For JavaFX you'll need JavaFX plugin: [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html).

Comment: Thank you. I've made basic GUI just using Jframe built in class. I'll look into those.